# Losing variable while threading C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, variables

I'm trying to deserialize xml file to list, and I want the user to be able to choose the file to deserialize.

```
static List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
string filename;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
    newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newThread.Start();

}
public void ThreadMethod()
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.ShowDialog();

    filename = dlg.FileName;

}

protected void ButtonDeserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        var other = (List<string>)(serializer.Deserialize(stream));
        mylist.Clear();
        mylist.AddRange(other);
    }
}
```

After the threading is finished, the filename becomse null.
Any idea why it happens?
By the way, I had to make the openfiledialog like this, because it's the only method that worked for me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really wouldn't use multiple threads for UI work anyway - you can do the *deserialization* in a different thread, but that's a different matter. Have you added logging to check whether it's actually getting to the `filename` assignment line? Perhaps an exception is being thrown?

Comment: Wait, you are using OpenFileDialog on a Web Application? wut?

Comment: I am really surprised OpenFileDialog doesn't cause exception or doesn't work in another way in Web Application. Anyway I don't see how it can be useful.

Comment: How can I do it without multiple threads? The other ways I tried gave me errors:
-Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."-

Comment: The problem is that you look like you are developing a web page and `OpenFileDialog` is for winforms type stuff. You probably want a fileupload control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Used the FileUploadControl and it solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

Replace This:

```
dlg.ShowDialog();
filename = dlg.FileName;
```

With This:

```
DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if(result == DialogResult.OK)   
  filename = dlg.FileName;
```

Comment: Didn't work, still losing variable. the filename becomse null.

   "Path cannot be null.
   Parameter name: path"

Comment: Your filename is non volatile and you are not setting a memory barrier - it is quite likely that the variable is lost between processor core caches. YOu need to set a memory barrier to synchronize caches AND declare the variable volatile. Easiest: use a Interlocked method to write to the variable, that sets implicit barriers.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem by using FileUploadControl. Much easier and working perfect on Web Application.

```
protected void ButtonDeserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            pathname = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LabelMessage.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```